# Why do we need the "subgradient inequality" here?

Tags: linear-programming, subgradient

So, I don't quite know what the "subgradient inequality is".

But, we have a function $Q(x)$ which is the optimal objective value of a linear programming problem. So, $Q(x) = \min_y \{ \ c^Ty\  |\  \text{s.t.} \ Ay = b - Tx, y \ge 0\}$.

This $Q(x)$ is assumed to be *convex*.

Let $z_0$ be the *dual* solutions to that linear program for some $x_0$. Then for this $x_0$, we have $$Q(x_0) = z_0^T(b - Tx_0)$$
which just says that the optimal value of the primal equals optimal value of the dual.

Now, my textbook says that "because $Q$ is convex and because of the *subgradient inequality*, we have for all $x$" $$Q(x) \ge z_0^T(b - Tx)$$

Could somebody please explain what this means? Why do we need convexity and what is the subgradient inequality, and how does the above equation follow from it?

Does the inequality not just follow directly from the fact that the dual solution $z_0$ is now just *some* feasible solution and therefore due to weak duality, we have that the dual objective value $z_0^T(b - Tx)$ is a lower bound on the optimal value $Q(x)$? So what do I need the "subgradient inequality" for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Math.SE!

The subgradient inequality is the generalization of the inequality

$$ f(y)\geqslant f(x)+\nabla f(x)^\text{T}(y-x) $$

to convex functions which aren't differentiable (such as piecewise-linear convex functions, as in this example). See [these slides](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/subgradients.pdf) for an illustration of the geometry of subgradients.

> Does the inequality not just follow directly from the fact that the dual solution $z_0$ is now just some feasible solution

Indeed it does. In fact, this is exactly how Van Slyke and Wets prove this result in [their original paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9080/cae3e3f2bf4dd3c11bf32ef7c9c3e9975f11.pdf) (see Proposition 3)! Invoking the subgradient inequality is just an alternative, (arguably) more sophisticated way to prove the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering though, in this particular case $Q(x)$ is piece-wise linear, and we are attempting to prove that $$z_0^T(b - Tx)$$ are supporting hyperplanes for those linear pieces. My thinking was that using the subgradient inequality rather than weak duality to prove $Q(x) \ge z_0^T(b - Tx)$ makes it more clear that they really are supporting hyperplanes, and not just any random lower bounds? Or is it somehow obvious that they are hyperplanes, without needing subgradient inequality?

Comment: All that is required to show that they are supporting hyperplanes is to show that they are valid lower bounds, and that there exists a point that satisfies them with equality (that’s the “supporting” part). In this case, $x_0$ is that point, so they are indeed supporting hyperplanes. I don’t like the subgradient approach as much, because it’s not very clear that the inequalities are actually supporting hyperplanes.